# awk: look for duplicated fields in multiple columns, print new column under condition

Tags: awk

I would like your help with awk. 
I am trying to look for lines where column `$1`and `$2`are duplicated in the file and where at least one of the duplicate has the value `ref`in column `$3`. If so, print a `"1"`else print `"2"` in new column.

An example of input file would be:

```
a       123     exp_a
a       123     ref
b       146     exp_a
c       156     ref
d       205     exp_a
d       205     exp_b
```

And the output file would be:

```
a       123     exp_a     1
a       123     ref       1
b       146     exp_a     2
c       156     ref       2
d       205     exp_a     2
d       205     exp_b     2
```

Here, `a    123` is duplicated with one line having `ref` at `$3`so it gets a `1`. In contrast, the others are either not duplicated at `$1`and `$2`or duplicated but with no `ref` at `$3`, so they get a `2`.

After some fiddling around, I manage to put a `1`at lines where `$1`and `$2`are duplicated but it does not take the `ref` at `$3` into account and I cannot tell awk to print a `2` otherwise... SPOILERS: my code is probably very ugly.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {i=$1FS$2} {a[i]=!a[i]?$3:a[i]FS"1\n" i"\t"$3FS"1"} END {for (l in a) {print l,a[l]}}' infile > outfile
```

The output I get is:

```
d       205     exp_a   1
d       205     exp_b   1
a       123     exp_a   1
a       123     ref     1
b       146     exp_a
c       156     ref
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR {
    cnt2[$1,$2]++
    cnt3[$1,$2,$3]++
    next
}
{ print $0, (cnt2[$1,$2]>1 && cnt3[$1,$2,"ref"]>0 ? 1 : 2) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file file
a       123     exp_a   1
a       123     ref     1
b       146     exp_a   2
c       156     ref     2
d       205     exp_a   2
d       205     exp_b   2
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Really neat!

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2]++;b[$1,$2]=$3;next} {$NF=(b[$1,$2]=="ref" && a[$1,$2]>1?$NF OFS "1":$NF OFS "2")} 1' OFS="\t"  Input_file  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2]++
  b[$1,$2]=$3
  next
}
{
  $NF=(b[$1,$2]=="ref" && a[$1,$2]>1?$NF OFS "1":$NF OFS "2")
}
1
' OFS="\t" Input_file Input_file
```

Comment: Your command is close to what I would like. The problem is that it prints a `1` when `$3` is `"ref"` but when there is no `"exp"` with the same `$1` and `$2`. For example, with your command, I get a `"1"` at line  `c   156   ref` when it should be `"2"`.
I edited my question to make this clearer.
Also, I tried to put a `2`or `3` instead of the `1`("will print the edited/non-edited line..." and I got the same result. Is that normal?

Comment: Also - it'll fail  when `x y ref` occurs before `x y foo` since `b[x,y]` will just contain `foo` on the 2nd pass. The fix would look a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277111/1745001 :-).

Comment: @Agathe, please check my EDIT and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 the edited script corrected the error mentioned in my comment above but as @Ed Morton said, it fails to correctly assign the `1`and `2` when the `ref` lines are before the `exp` lines. It is not something I mentioned in the initial question but having not the be careful about where the `ref` are in my ìnfile` is something appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This one works in one go of the data but expects the file to be ordered by `$1 $2`, the "key". Records within each "key" group are outputed in random order (`for(i in a)`):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    if((p!=$1 OFS $2) && NR>1) {            # when the $1 $2 changes from previous
        for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++) {              # iterate and output buffered records
            print p,a[i],2-(a[-1]&&a[0]>1)  # more than one record in buffer and ...
        }                                   # ... ref for $4=1
        delete a                            # empty buffer after output
    }
    if($3=="ref")                           # if there is a match in $3
        a[-1]++                             # increase counter
    a[++a[0]]=$3                            # buffer records to a, a[0] counter
    p=$1 OFS $2                             # p is for previous "key"
}
END {
    for(i=1;i<=a[0];i++)                    # duplicate code from above if
        print p,a[i],2-(a[-1]&&a[0]>1)
}' file
```

Outputs:

```
a       123     exp_a   1
a       123     ref     1
b       146     exp_a   2
c       156     ref     2
d       205     exp_a   2
d       205     exp_b   2
```

Record counter `a[0]` and ref counter `a[-1]` are in `a[]` to reset them with a single `delete a`.